# Polynomal operator

Tags: matrices, nilpotence

Let $L : V \to V$ be an operator on an $n$-dimensional complex vector space. Show if  $p \in \mathbb{C}[t]$, the operator $p(L)$ is nilpotent if and only if the eigenvalues of $L$ are roots of $p$. What goes wrong in the real case when $p(t) = t^2 + 1$ and the dimension of $V$ is odd?

I understand the first part, since an operator is nilpotent if and only if all its eigenvalues are $0$, and the complex eigenvalues of $p(L)$ are given by $p(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is a complex eigenvalue of $L$.

I don't see why this doesn't also apply in the real case though, since we could just view the operator as a operator on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and conclude that the complex eigenvalues must be roots of $p$. In fact the claim seems necessarily false, since if $V$ is an odd-dimensional real vector space $L$ must have a real eigenvalue $\lambda$. But then $\lambda^2 + 1 \neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $L^2 + I$, thus $L^2 + I$ cannot be nilpotent.

Comment: How does that example contradict the theorem? The theorem has the form $A \iff B$. Your example has $A,B$ both false.

Comment: I'm saying the second question seems to want you to find an operator on an odd-dimensional real vector space such that $L^2 + 1$ is nilpotent. But that seems to be impossible.

Comment: The question asked "what goes wrong"? It didn't ask you to find $L$. But I see your issue. The theorem still holds in the real case, but sometimes vacuously (e,g., for $p(t)=t^2+1$).

Comment: If $V$ is an odd-dimensional real vector  space, there are no operators $L$ such that all eigenvalues of $L$ are roots of $p$, and there are no operators $L$ such that $L^2 + I$ is nilpotent. So although the author's question "what goes wrong ...?" is a little confusing, the answer to the question is that _nothing_ goes wrong!

Comment: Your objection is a good one (+1). The author was either being deliberately _sneaky_ (asking what goes wrong when in actuality, nothing goes wrong), or else, the author actually failed to understand that the theorem still holds for real vector spaces. I suspect  it was the "deliberately sneaky" case.

Comment: At most, things go wrong in the real case and **even** dimensions and with many polynomials $p$: If $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $L=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$, then the complex eigenvalue $i$ is not an eigenvalue of this *real* matrix  because there is no eigenvector $v\in\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ with $Lv=iv$. Hence vacuously all (non-existent) eigenvalues of $L$ are roots of $p(x)=x$ and yet $p(L)$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: To my understanding, for an $n{\times}n$ real matrix $A$ (regarded as a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$), complex non-real eigenvalues of $A$, if any, are still considered to be eigenvalues of $A$ (even though there is no corresponding real eigenvector).